# os.makedir race condition in single thread? How to ensure directory created before continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, operating-system, race-condition

I have very strange behavior of `os.makedir` in flask application.

I have an API endpoint for images upload. Each image should be grouped into directories based on conditions. If directory not exists, the directory should be created.

Initially, I had this code in my app:

```
    # create needed dir if doesn't exist
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(abs_path)):
        os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(abs_path))

    # create a file and save it into a needed place
    with open(abs_path, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fp, f)
        f.flush()
```

And in 90% of cases, it works great. But when there was two files in the request, that should be placed in same directory, and the directory was not yet created I got this:

```
flask_1  |   File "/app/storage.py", line 101, in save_file
flask_1  |     os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(abs_path))
flask_1  | FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/static/df273d04909e71beb8b63b4d1b1c0a969ee6fc15'
```

It can be reproduced locally with 100% success in flask debug mode with 1 thread. Seems it is some kind of Linux/docker or some cache race condition.

Then I changed code simply to this one:

```
if not os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(abs_path)):
    try:
        os.mkdir(os.path.dirname(abs_path))
    except FileExistsError:
        # Another thread was already created the directory when
        # several simultaneous requests has come
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(abs_path)):
            pass
        else:
            raise

    # create a file and save it into a needed place
    with open(abs_path, 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fp, f)
        f.flush()
```

And problem is gone.

But I have concerns about using this code in production, as it is very strange that the same check does different results.

How to ensure that the directory really created before continue first request processing?

P.S. Files are in place, with second code snippet both files in place. With the first one only first file in directory and error on second.

I.E. With first code snippet Flask thinks that everything ok and continue

Comment: You are certain that the process is running in a single thread?

Answer (score 0):

[os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) accepts a parameter `exist_ok` that when is `True` it will not raise an error if the dir exists

```
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(abs_path), exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Yep, I know this option. But I and my team-lead mostly want to understand internal process, not just handle the error.